# Why are there an error to importing nlp module of pycaret?

Tags: python, nlp, pycaret

I've been trying to import the pycaret "nlp" module into a colab notebook but I've gotten the following error:

***ImportError: cannot import name 'nlp' from 'pycaret' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pycaret/init.py).***

I come here because ChatGPT doesn't have the answer yet.

1. I opened a notebook in Colab.
2. I Loaded the pycaret library:
   ***!pip install pycaret[full]***
3. I imported the nlp module:
   ***from pycaret import nlp***
4. Finally got the error message already mentioned at the beginning.
   I hope there is a satisfactory resolution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code on Colab and also on my local machine. I received the same error message as you did each time, so I don't think this relates to Colab.

When I run `from pycaret.datasets import get_data` this worked fine on both Colab and my local machine. So pycaret does seem to be installed.

Have you successfully run `from pycaret import nlp` on another project? If so I suggest checking the version of pycaret and try installing this specific version on Colab.

EDIT:
The nlp module has been removed from pycaret. See this [LINK](https://github.com/pycaret/pycaret/issues/3099). So you would need to run an earlier version of pycaret.

Answer (score 0):

The NLP module was deprecated from `pycaret` 3.0.0 onwards. See details here: https://github.com/pycaret/pycaret/releases/tag/3.0.0

If you want to use the NLP module, you should use an older version of `pycaret` (2.3.x).